# Executando Query com SUM em HQL?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

Estou tentando usar o `SUM` para somar um atributo de uma entidade usando `HQL` do `NHibernate`, mas sempre que executo a `query` retorna vazia.

Estou seguindo o exemplo [aqui](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/pt-BR/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation) mas ainda não consegui fazer. Como fazer isso ?

Estou tentando assim.

```
public IList<Conta> findAllContasReceber() 
{
    ISession _session = getSession();
    String SQL = "SELECT c.cliente, c.historico, c.dtLancamento, c.dtVencimento, SUM(c.valorPagar), " +
                 "c.valorAcrescimo, c.valorFinal, c.dtPagamento, c.tipoConta, c.planoConta, c.status, c.venda " +
                 "FROM Conta c WHERE (c.tipoConta = 1) AND (c.status = 0) GROUP BY c.dtVencimento, c.cliente ORDER BY c.dtVencimento";

    IList<Conta> list = _session.CreateQuery(SQL).List<Conta>();

    return list;
}
```

**Entidade**

```
[Serializable]
public class Conta 
{    
     public virtual long id                      { set; get; }        
     public virtual Cliente cliente              { set; get; }
     public virtual String historico             { set; get; }
     public virtual DateTime dtLancamento        { set; get; }
     public virtual DateTime dtVencimento        { set; get; }
     public virtual decimal valorPagar           { set; get; } //total vendas
     public virtual decimal valorAcrescimo       { set; get; } //total acrescimo
     public virtual decimal valorFinal           { set; get; } //total pagar

     public virtual DateTime dtPagamento         { set; get; }
     public virtual int tipoConta                { set; get; }  //1 receber, 2 pagar
     public virtual PlanoDeConta planoConta      { set; get; }
     public virtual int status                   { set; get; } //0 ativa, 1 fechada, 2 cancelada, 3 aguardando pagamento
     public virtual Venda venda                  { set; get; }


     public Conta() 
     {                
     }   


}
```

Comment: Acredito, por essa SQL não vai retornar os dados dessa consulta, porque, a classe precisaria de um join por campos de agregação como `Cliente` e `PlanoDeConta`. Faz um teste não retorne um tipo `Conta` retorna a lista pura para ver se retorna algum valor da tabela, tipo `_session.CreateQuery(SQL).List()` tem essa opção se tiver verifique se ele te retorna valores?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic acredito que o C# nao permite retornar uma lista pura como vc flw, eh necessario informar o tipo da lista por exemplo: `List<String>` ou `List<Object>` algo assim. Estou tentando retornar apenas `List` e pede um argumento.

Comment: deixa eu dar uma olhada aqui tem um exemplo pronto em meu pc e já te falo, ok?

Comment: ele retorna um método sem paramento também ou seja, tipo de retorna de `List` sem tipo `session.CreateQuery("").List()`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic sim, mas na assinatura do metodo eu não consigo colocar esse retorno `public List findAllContasReceber()`.

Comment: porque o retorno é `System.Collections.IList SqlQuery(string sql);` a assinatura correta!, primeiro eu quero ver se retorna alguma coisa, `public System.Collections.IList findAllContasReceber() `

Comment: sim, mas o `IList` tbm precisa ser tipado, tipo `IList<String>` ou `IList<Object` ou como no meu caso `IList<Conta>`.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46345/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-fernandopaiva).

Comment: System.Collections.IList esse é o tipo correto, inclusive isso é só um teste para verificar se retorna algo.!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic problema resolvido, postei a solução. Abraço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido. Depois de muito pesquisar uma maneira de fazer isso e os motivos da exception encontrei uma maneira de fazer. Enfim, funcionou 100%.

Fiz assim.

```
public IList<Conta> findAllContasReceber() {
            ISession _session = getSession();
            String SQL = "SELECT new Conta(c.cliente, c.historico, c.dtLancamento, c.dtVencimento, SUM(c.valorPagar), SUM(c.valorAcrescimo), SUM(c.valorFinal), c.status) " + 
                         "FROM Conta c WHERE (c.tipoConta = 1) AND (c.status = 0) " + 
                         "GROUP BY c.cliente, c.dtVencimento " + 
                         "ORDER BY c.dtVencimento ";
            IList<Conta> list = _session.CreateQuery(SQL).List<Conta>();
            return list;
        }
```

E criei um construtor na entidade

```
[Serializable]
    public class Conta {

        public virtual long id                      { set; get; }        
        public virtual Cliente cliente              { set; get; }
        public virtual String historico             { set; get; }
        public virtual DateTime dtLancamento        { set; get; }
        public virtual DateTime dtVencimento        { set; get; }
        public virtual decimal valorPagar           { set; get; } //total vendas
        public virtual decimal valorAcrescimo       { set; get; } //total acrescimo
        public virtual decimal valorFinal           { set; get; } //total pagar
        public virtual DateTime dtPagamento         { set; get; }
        public virtual int tipoConta                { set; get; }  //1 receber, 2 pagar
        public virtual PlanoDeConta planoConta      { set; get; }
        public virtual int status                   { set; get; } //0 ativa, 1 fechada, 2 cancelada, 3 aguardando pagamento
        public virtual Venda venda                  { set; get; }


        public Conta() {
        }

        public Conta(Cliente cliente, String historico, DateTime dtLancamento, DateTime dtVencimento, 
                    decimal valorPagar, decimal valorAcrescimo, decimal valorFinal, int status){

                        this.cliente = cliente;
                        this.historico = historico;
                        this.dtLancamento = dtLancamento;
                        this.dtVencimento = dtVencimento;
                        this.valorPagar = valorPagar;
                        this.valorAcrescimo = valorAcrescimo;
                        this.valorFinal = valorFinal;
                        this.status = status;
        }

    }
```